# Prove that Det(A-E)=0 if and only if AC=C

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have some $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $n \times 1$ vector C. Let $E$ be the identity matrix. $$Det(A-E)=0 \iff AC=C.$$

Me and a few friends have been trying to prove it, but none of us could. Thank you!

Comment: what is E here?

Comment: Could it be the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes, E is identity matrix

Comment: If $c$ is the column of $C$ then $Ac = c$. This says that $(A-I)c = 0$, hence $A-I$ has an eigenvalue of 0. For the other direction, if $\det (A-I) = 0$ there is some $v$ such that $(A-I)v=0$, let $C$ be the matrix with $v$ as the only non-zero column.

Comment: I don't think your statement is true as written. I believe the correct one is "Det$(A-E) = 0$ if and only if *there exists* some $C$ such that $AC=C$."

This can't always be true about some arbitrary $C$ chosen beforehand. This would mean that every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 0):

you need to know that $det(A)$ if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent. once you have that, applying it to the matrix $A_I$ tells you that there is a nonzero vector $c$ such that $(A_I)c = 0$. that means $$Ac = c, c \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

note as $\det(A-I)=0$ therefore $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ so there has to be an eigenvector corresponding to it which is $c$